# How to compare two CSV file?

Tags: java, csv, geolocation

I have two CSV file 1st one IP Geo-location CSV file and second one have date time and IP address how to compare both file and make new CSV file have date time IP address and IP location(country name).How to make it in java?

1st File

```
18102015 11:35:59  93.178.13.37:2065
18102015 11:36:00  93.178.13.37:2078
18102015 11:36:21  93.178.13.37:7251
18102015 11:37:05  222.35.153.160:502
18102015 11:37:05  222.35.153.160:5050
```

2nd File

```
93.178.0.0  93.178.63.255   1571946496  1571962879  SA  Saudi Arabia
93.178.64.0 93.178.127.255  1571962880  1571979263  RU  Russian Federation
222.16.0.0  222.95.255.255  3725590528  3730833407  CN  China
```

I want Result:

```
18102015 11:35:59  93.178.13.37   2065    SA  Saudi Arabia 
18102015 11:36:00  93.178.13.37   2078    SA  Saudi Arabia
18102015 11:36:21  93.178.13.37   7251    SA  Saudi Arabia
18102015 11:37:05  222.35.153.160  5029    CN   China  
18102015 11:37:05  222.35.153.160  5050    CN   China
```

Comment: Did you try doing anything yet?

Comment: Are you required to do this in JAVA?  Can you please provide a small example of both files.

Comment: Sir I m edit question please see.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Think of a dotted IP address as 4 octets of a 32 bit number.  For example, the IP address 93.178.63.255 is really (93*(2^24)) + (178*(2^16)) + (63*(2^8)) + 255.  Do the math, and you come up with a number that represents the IP address.
- The second file has IP ranges (low to high).  If you convert the low and high IP addresses of the range, you'll come up with two numbers.  Therefore, if you're trying to detect if a certain IP address (from file #1) is within a range (in file #2), it's simple.  if IP >= lowIP && IP <= highIP it's in the range.
- Further advice: parse file #2 and create objects for each of them.  The object will have most notably the starting IP address, the ending IP address, and the country.  Then you can parse file #1, search within your collection of objects for a match, and then output what you need to.